# FadeIn and FadeOut Theme Animation works only once and only one way,why?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

Anyone can help me please?
What I'm trying to do is, make a random quote fading in and out on my textblock.
I'm trying to use something called "FadeInThemeAnimation".
The thing is that I don't know how to make it work endlessly ,so that my random quote appears and disappears after the time a set up. I've tested a dozen attributes in xaml to see what happens but it seems like I have no clue what to do.  At the moment the quote appears in the textblock(without any fade in effect) and slowly fades out, that is it. Please , how do I make it work. I'm pasting in a chunk of xaml code I have got.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="FamousQuoteTextBlock" Grid.Row="4" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,5,5,5"
                   FontSize="15" TextAlignment="Justify" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                   Loaded="FamousQuoteTextBlock_Loaded"
                   FontFamily="Edwardian Script ITC"
                   DataContext="{Binding quote}"
                   Text="{Binding RandomQuote,Mode=TwoWay}"
                   />
        <StackPanel>
                <StackPanel.Resources>
                <Storyboard x:Name="EnterStoryboard">
                    <FadeInThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FamousQuoteTextBlock"/>
                </Storyboard>
                <Storyboard x:Name="ExitStoryboard">
                    <FadeOutThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FamousQuoteTextBlock"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </StackPanel.Resources>
        </StackPanel>
```

I have tried to use something like speedratio,duratio and so on to see what happens but it didn't make any difference:(

My C# code behind:

```
        private void FamousQuoteTextBlock_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            Delay(sender, e);

        }

        private async void Delay(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));

            generator_Tick(this, e);
            DispatcherTimer generator = new DispatcherTimer();
            generator.Tick += generator_Tick;
            generator.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            generator.Start();


        }


        private void generator_Tick(object sender, object e)
        {
            Quote quote = new Quote();
            FamousQuoteTextBlock.DataContext = quote;
            quote.GenerateQuote();

 }
```

Comment: Inside the Storyboard, you can use a DoubleAnimation which targets the Opacity. There is also possbile to set a behaviour to run endlessly and to reverse the animation (meaning a fade in will then result in a fade out).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own animation like this :

```
<TextBlock x:Name="QuoteTextBlock" Text="My Quote here">
    <TextBlock.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="FadeStoryboard">
            <DoubleAnimation From="1" To="0.1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" 
                                 Storyboard.TargetName="QuoteTextBlock" 
                                 RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True">
                <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                    <CubicEase/>
                </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
            </DoubleAnimation>
        </Storyboard>
    </TextBlock.Resources>
</TextBlock>
```

And start it like this :

```
var storyboard = QuoteTextBlock.Resources["FadeStoryboard"] as Storyboard;

if (storyboard != null)
{
    storyboard.Begin();
}
```

The small tricks you were looking for were `AutoReverse` which means that after the animation is performed, the reverse animation will follow up. If combined with `RepeatBehaviour="Forever"`, it might achieve what you were looking for.

I've added an `Ease`. You can customize the easing function a lot. It means that the animation step won't be performed in a *linear* manner, but in this case will be *cubic*.

Some links which can provide you with more details on this matter :

[MSDN : Quickstart - Animating your UI using XAML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh452703.aspx)

[MSDN : Storyboarded Animations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj819807.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot . You have been very helpful.  As You can see I'm a beginner. Do You know any book I could learn  Xaml from basics to advance concepts like animation?

Comment: The links I have provided you with should help for now. There are many video tutorials on MVA (Microsoft Virtual Academy) for building Universal Apps (Windows 8.1 + Windows Phone 8.1 altogether). And their free. just have a look at them.

Comment: how to make it run just one time with auto reverse

Comment: Don't use RepeatBehavior="Forever".